# Insert row in TableLayoutPanel at design time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, design-time, tablelayoutpanel

At design time, I want to insert a row in a large TableLayoutPanel.

I want to insert an empty row, say at position 2, and have the contents of rows 2 through N move to rows 3 to N+1.

All I can find is the Add Row link, which adds a row at the end. Then I would have to manually move all the items in each cell down to the lower cell (which will take me 30 minutes) to free the row that I want to insert. Of course, I'd rather not have to do that.

Comment: At design time, you can edit the rows of a tablelayoutpanel and in the dialog is a insert button for rows. Place your cursor at row 2, click insert, and you get a new row inserted at row 2. Rows 2-N are moved down. Did you mean to ask a different question?

Comment: > Click insert.... Where? I don't see an "Insert" button or link in the Properties window. I must be blind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the arrow, or in Properties sheet, select rows and click the ellipsis button.
[image: Click that little arrow button]

You will see a dialog.

[image: Rows Dialog]

Select Rows from dropdown at top, and then position highlight and click insert.

Answer (score 3):

You can right click the row where you want to add the new empty row, got `Row` and click `Insert`. This will insert a new row at the selected location.

[image]